# Taskschd.msc / SCHTASKS "The user account you are operating under does not have permission..."

Tags: windows-10, cmd.exe, windows-update, windows-task-scheduler

Been receiving the following error when trying to modify tasks with **taskschd.msc** and **SCHTASKS** (in CMD prompt).

Specifically in the **UpdateOrchestrator** folder/directory of "C:\Windows\System32\Tasks\Microsoft\Windows".

**"The user account you are operating under does not have permission to modify this task"**

When using taskschd.msc.

Also,
**Error: Access is Denied**

When using SCHTASKS.

Can anyone explain a *proven* way to gain privileges to modify tasks in this folder *without* using 3rd party application (such as PSEXEC or NSudo).

Yes, I am launching both **taskschd.msc** and **CMD Prompt** as *administrator*.

**EDIT:** This specific question has **not** been answered despite Moderators claiming it has. The solutions provided in other threads either involve **PSEXEC/NSudo** or provide a solution that is not effective (Deleting registry keys to cause the keys to repopulate with different settings).

Comment: Questions: (1) Have you run cmd using Run As Administrator?, (2) Does your account account have a password? (3) Try it with UAC disabled.

Comment: In my UpdateOrchestrator folder, the administrators group has full control only for some of the tasks, and on others it has write but not modify.  Which one are you trying to modify, and why?

Comment: Good q, but the answer seem to be "no". I personally used AdvancedRun (from Nirsoft) because unlike psexec it does not seem to install a backdoor service. And unlike Nsudo, AdvancedRun is signed so less hassle to run. You must run e.g. a cmd.exe as SYSTEM acount (with AdvancedRun). It will look exactly like an Administrator one, but `schtasks /Change /Disable /TN "\Microsoft\Windows\UpdateOrchestrator\Reboot"` will work from it; prints "SUCCESS: ..." and if you have an opened taskschd and F5 (refresh) in it, the Reboot task immediately shows as disabled.

Comment: You can double check that your cmd.exe is running as SYSTEM with task manager (under "details" in `Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19042.804]`). Regular administrator cmd.exe will actually show up as running under your own user name (the elevation is indirect), whereas those launched as SYSTEM user (e.g. with AdvancedRun) will properly show as running under the SYSTEM account.

Comment: @harrymc: Those are different things. Another way to check the SYSTEM elevation. Regular administrator cmd.exe (e.g. launched with start+r ctrl+shift+enter or "run as administrator" right click) responds as/with your own user name to `whoami` (despite the window title having "administrator" in it), whereas the true SYSTEM cmd responds with `nt authority\system`. The former uses an indirect form of elevation, which is more secure but doesn't get some stuff done.